# Ascending sum sql Oracle

Tags: sql, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have problem with query sql

```
SELECT 
ID_TRANSACTION AS id,
PAID_AMOUNT_PLN AS paid_amount,
D_PAYMENT
FROM AB 
--WHERE D_PAYMENT <= '20190808'
)
```

[image]

I would like the query to count the sum depending on D_PAYMENT according to the condition D_PAYMENT <= 'data'
That is, if D_PAYMENT <= 20190731 then 362.07
if D_PAYMENT <= 20190808 then 362,07 + 87,48 and so on

Anyone can help me how to do this?

Comment: You have tagged [db2] and [oracle-sqldeveloper]. Are you really using SQL developer to connect to a DB2 database or, if not, which RDBMS are you actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and then `SUM` the amounts after filtering on the `D_PAYMENT` column:

```sql
SELECT id_transaction AS id,
       SUM( paid_amount_plan ) AS paid_amount,
       MAX( d_payment ) AS d_payment
FROM   ab
WHERE  d_payment <= DATE '2019-08-09'
GROUP BY id_transaction;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ab (
  id_transaction   VARCHAR(20),
  paid_amount_plan NUMERIC(5,2),
  d_payment        DATE
);
INSERT INTO ab ( id_transaction, paid_amount_plan, d_payment )
VALUES ( '0009015890', 362.07, DATE '2019-07-31' );
INSERT INTO ab ( id_transaction, paid_amount_plan, d_payment )
VALUES ( '0009015890', 87.48, DATE '2019-08-08' );
INSERT INTO ab ( id_transaction, paid_amount_plan, d_payment )
VALUES ( '0009015890', 304.96, DATE '2019-08-12' );
```

Outputs:

> ```
>         ID | PAID_AMOUNT |  D_PAYMENT
> ---------: | ----------: | ---------:
> 0009015890 |      449.55 | 2019-08-08
> ```

---

Or, if you want all rows, use an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id_transaction AS id,
       SUM( paid_amount_plan )
         OVER ( PARTITION BY id_transaction ORDER BY d_payment )
         AS paid_amount,
       d_payment
FROM   ab
WHERE  d_payment <= DATE '2019-08-09';
```

Which outputs:

> ```
>         ID | PAID_AMOUNT |  D_PAYMENT
> ---------: | ----------: | ---------:
> 0009015890 |      362.07 | 2019-07-31
> 0009015890 |      449.55 | 2019-08-08
> ```

*DB2 db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=cbe38555ad198bd8ac926ef5a2ce4d87)*

*Oracle db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cbe38555ad198bd8ac926ef5a2ce4d87)*